# How to use salvattore in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to get [salvattore](https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore) to work in my embercli project.  Currently I've followed the example at [salvattore.com](http://salvattore.com/) and it sort of works but puts '3 .column.size-1of3' on the grid div rather than creating column divs in the grid.

example html

```
<div id="grid" data-columns="">  <!-- (inspector style) content: '3 .column.size-1of3';  -->
  <div>Item #1</div>
  <div>Item #2</div>
  <div>Item #3</div>
  <div>Item #20</div>
</div>
```

I think this is happening because Salvattore isn't being inited at the correct time so the DOM isn't ready for it.  I've tried creating a view with a didInsertElement function but I don't know how to get the Salvattore namespace to rerun the grid function. Currently I get the error with the code below.

Build error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/mikev/dev/derp-ember-app/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-YVY49mzP.tmp/salvattore.js'
```

index view:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import salvattore from 'salvattore';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        salvattore.register_grid();
        salvattore.recreate_columns();
    }
});
```

Any insight to my problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you importing the salvattore js file into your project?

Comment: `app.import('vendor/salvattore/dist/salvattore.js');`

I see it in my vendor.js file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are placing it now in is the right spot, as that's not going to be application global. Try:

**app/views/application.js**

```
/* globals salvattore */
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  _myUiInit: function () {
    salvattore.register_grid();
    salvattore.recreate_columns();
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

The import should look like:

**Brocfile.js**

```
app.import( 'vendor/salvattore/dist/salvattore.js' );
```

(and restart the ember server after)

Note: the above is untested (I don't use salvattore) but I use the exact same approach with Foundation, just the init function content is different.

Comment: I had the same brocfile.js.  I am still stuck on the import issue.  I am wondering if [salvattore.js](https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore/blob/master/dist/salvattore.js) is written to work with import.  Still new to ES6 modules.

Comment: Eh, no, probably not (looking at the code) ... I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, it's working now.  No need for the import.  I also had to find the grid object first.  `var grid = $('#grid')[0];
        salvattore.register_grid(grid);`  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'd also like to add.  If you're working with handlebars in emberjs.  The metamorph content doesn't play nicely with salvattore.  I ended up having to add `$('#grid script').remove();` before register_grid().